# Spring freezing if sending zero length header

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm developing a Spring MVC Rest Api and it is token based API. I'm sending X-Token header for every request. I have a method which name is checkToken. When I send zero length token to this method then spring is not responsing.

I'm using Jetty 9, Spring 4.3.6-RELEASE. This is my checkToken method content:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/auth/checkToken", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Object checkToken(HttpServletRequest request) throws InvalidTokenException {
    ClientUtils.checkValidToken(request, jedisPoolContainer.getJedisPool().getResource());

    SuccessResult result = new SuccessResult();
    return result;
}
```

And ClientUtils class methods:

```
public static boolean isValidToken(HttpServletRequest request, Jedis jedis) {
    Token token = ClientUtils.getValidToken(request, jedis);
    if (token != null)
        return true;
    return false;
}

public static void checkValidToken(HttpServletRequest request, Jedis jedis) throws InvalidTokenException {
    logger.debug("ClientUtils.isValidToken(request, jedis): " + ClientUtils.isValidToken(request, jedis));

    if (ClientUtils.isValidToken(request, jedis) == false)
        throw new InvalidTokenException();
}

public static Token getValidToken(HttpServletRequest request, Jedis jedis) {
    logger.debug("request.getHeader(TOKEN_HTTP_NAME): " + request.getHeader(TOKEN_HTTP_NAME));

    if (request.getHeader(TOKEN_HTTP_NAME) == null)
        return null;

    if (request.getHeader(TOKEN_HTTP_NAME).length() != 32)
        return null;

    String rawTokenData = jedis.hget(JedisPoolContainer.TOKENS, request.getHeader(TOKEN_HTTP_NAME));
    if (rawTokenData == null)
        return null;

    rawTokenData = rawTokenData.replace("\\", "");
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss").create();
    Token token = gson.fromJson(rawTokenData, Token.class);
    if (token.getIpAddress().equals(ClientUtils.getClientIpAddr(request)))
        return token;

    return null;
}
```

CorsFilter class is:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, POST, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            "Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, X-Token");
    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
}
```

Spring doesn't return any response when send "X-Token: " header with zero length. I'm stopping Jetty with CTRL+C then spring throwing these exceptions:

```
[INFO] Stopped ServerConnector@30741e9b{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8888}
[INFO] Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher'
INFO (AbstractApplicationContext.java:987) Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Wed Oct 18 21:54:38 EEST 2017]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
[INFO] Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO (AbstractApplicationContext.java:987) Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Oct 18 21:54:35 EEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
[INFO] Stopped o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@2f16c21f{/,file:///home/emir/workspacejava/SpringRestApi/src/main/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{file:///home/emir/workspacejava/SpringRestApi/src/main/webapp/}
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] 
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1684)
    at com.nixarsoft.restapi.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1667)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1121)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1055)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:170)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.web.method.ControllerAdviceBean.resolveBean(ControllerAdviceBean.java:146)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.getExceptionHandlerMethod(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:447)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:362)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:59)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1030)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    ... 31 more
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:170)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.web.method.ControllerAdviceBean.resolveBean(ControllerAdviceBean.java:146)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.getExceptionHandlerMethod(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:447)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:362)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:59)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1030)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    ... 31 more
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1684)
    at com.nixarsoft.restapi.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1667)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1121)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1055)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:170)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.web.method.ControllerAdviceBean.resolveBean(ControllerAdviceBean.java:146)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.getExceptionHandlerMethod(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:447)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:362)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:59)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1030)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    ... 31 more
[INFO] Jetty server exiting.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 31:25 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-10-18T21:56:21+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 50M/684M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
emir@bugra:~/workspacejava/SpringRestApi$
```

Where I'm making wrong? How can I handle these kind of problems? I don't want to stop Spring and it must work everytime.

Comment: Try to improve your code a little and run it in debug mode and see when the program stops responding.

In method checkValidToken:
Store the value of getValidToken in a variable and log the variable's value. Currently getValidToken queries 2 times your redis and one of the times is to only log the value.
Try to use placeholders for the logged string if the logger permits it (ex: logback). It will not perform concatenations if the message is not going to get logged.

The exception when closing the program is thrown because there is a request still being handled when you close the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. Spring is not freezing. I'm false using Jedis. JedisPool has 8 Jedis object in first. I'm trying to get Jedis from pool with this: `pool.getResource().hget("something", "something")` This returning Jedis object and every Jedis object HAS TO CLOSED. If you don't close these and try to get a new Jedis resource then you have to wait becouse JedisPool can't find a free Jedis object. This is wasted my 2 days :(